# What is a word for someone who will only take credit for something if it benefits them?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, someone who will not say they suggested the restaurant if someone in the group said they didn't like it.

Synynoms could include: noncommittal, unaccountable, fickle. Someone who frequently makes disclamers. Not able to take the blame or own up to bad decisions.

Comment: Your question reminds me of the proverb, "Success has many fathers, but failure is an orphan".

Answer (score 1):

Consider *[flip-flopper](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flip-flopper)*,  “A person, especially a politician, who changes his opinion”.  Also adjectives *[inconsistent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inconsistent#Adjective)*,  *[inconstant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inconstant#Adjective)*, *[wishy-washy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wishy-washy#Adjective)*, and *[vacillating](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vacillating#Adjective)* and the nouns *[fair weather friend](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fair-weather_friend#Noun)* and *[weathercock](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weathercock#Noun)*(“(figuratively) One who veers with every change of current opinion; a fickle, inconstant person”). [Sources: wiktionary]

It seems to me the words *[revisionist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revisionist)* and *[reversionist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reversionist?s=t)* ought to apply; but while the former has an appropriate sense (“a reviser”), it often is understood in its other senses: “an advocate of revision, especially of some political or religious doctrine” and “any advocate of doctrines, theories, or practices that depart from established authority or doctrine”; and *reversionist* often is understood in its sense “a person who advocates reverting to the conditions, customs, ideals, etc., of an earlier era” which is not quite appropriate. [Sources: dictionary.reference.com]

Answer (score 0):

I think [opportunist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Opportunist) could fit your description:

> - one who takes advantage of any opportunity to achieve an end, often with no regard for principles or consequences.
> - a person who adapts his actions, responses, etc, to take advantage of opportunities, circumstances, etc